# ionic gravar audio não tras para view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic, html5-audio

Fiz um app, para gravar audio, ele  abre a gravador nativo, mas não retorna o audio para view.

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaCapture) {
$scope.captureAudio = function () {
    var captureSuccess = function (mediaFiles) {
        var i, path, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
            // do something interesting with the file
        }
    };

    // capture error callback
    var captureError = function (error) {
        navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
    };

    // start audio capture
    navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {
        limit: 2
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rodrigo, Boa Noite,

Recomendo utilizar o seguinte plugin pra gravação de áudio: cordova-plugin-media-with-compression(https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-media-with-compression). Eu já utilizei e não tive problema nenhum.

Comment: Obrigado @JeordaneBatista.